# Why is the parameter inside the action coming back as undefined when using redux?

Tags: react-native, redux, action

Currently, I have a page which renders a list of dates, When a user presses a certain date, the user is then taken to a new page which renders the graph of the date that they pressed.

I want to use redux to update props, so that I can render a specific graph based on which button a user has pressed.

Inside my renderList() I return a mapped array that in turn returns a bunch of TouchableOpacities.  Inside each TouchableOpacity, inside the onPress event, another function is called that passes all of the information about the test as a parameter.  renderList looks like this.

```
let sorted = _.orderBy(this.props.testResults, testResult => testResult.created, 'desc');
        moment.locale(localeToMomentLocale(I18n.locale));
        return sorted.map((result, index) => {
            let formattedDate = moment(result.created).format(I18n.t('report_header_dformat'));
            let correctedDate = vsprintf(I18n.t('report_date_correction'), [formattedDate]);
            let analysis = TestAnalysis.run(result);
            return (
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => this.resultOrTest(result)}
                    style={styles.row} key={'_' + index}>
               </TouchableOpacity>
```

resultOrTest looks like this:

```
resultOrTest = (result) => {
        console.log('ReportDetailPage: resultOrTest: showing result: ', result.id);

        this.props.setResultIdToProps(result.id);
        this.props.navigation.navigate('ReportSinglePage');
    };
```

mapDispatchToProps looks like this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        setResultIdToProps: () => {
            dispatch(setResultIdToProps());
        }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ReportDetailPage);
```

inside my actions/user.js page.

```
export const setResultIdToProps = (resultId) => {
    // var newId = resultId.toString();
    console.log('actions/user.js setResultIdToProps: resultid.......', resultId);
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch({
            type: SET_RESULT_ID_TO_PROPS,
            resultId
        });
    }
};
```

Why does resultId keep coming back as undefined?  Did I pass the wrong value/Parameter?

Comment: can you try `resultId:resultId`?

Comment: vahissan provided the correct solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to properly pass the parameter to your action dispatcher in `mapDispatchToProps`. Right now, you're not passing the `resultId`, hence it is passed as `undefined`.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        setResultIdToProps: (resultId) => {
            dispatch(setResultIdToProps(resultId));
        }
    }
}
```